# How does packet routing take palce in Wifi-Direct group?

Tags: android, networking, wifi, wifi-direct

I am working on a peer to peer data transfer application using WiFi Direct. I can't seem to understand how the connection works in a WiFi Direct group. Does the Group owner act as an access point and is responsible for routing the packets between the clients? Or do the clients in a group send packets directly to each other?

I can't seem to find a clear explanation of how this works (I'm not talking about the implementation in an Android app).

Comment: Wi-Fi Direct established a pseudo WAP on one device. The devices in a group are all part of the same LAN, just as if they were connected to a real AP, so there is no routing between the devices in a group, just as there is no routing on a real WAP between the devices connected to it. A WAP is a layer-2 device, much like an ethernet switch.

Comment: @RonMaupin so am I right in understanding that any packet from one client to another client in a wifi direct group goes through the group owner?

Answer (score 0):

yes the Group owner act as an access point and is responsible for routing the packets between the clients.

1. WiFi Direct works in a star topology method. One peer is chosen to
   be the group owner. When connecting to an existing WiFi group, a
   peer can only obtain the IP address of the group’s owner and notify
   the owner of it’s presence.
2. The application requires a full-mesh topology. Therefore in our
   application, the owner of the group - who is the only peer known by
   all others, advertises a message containing  information about all
   the other peers.
3. When two peers belong to the same group and have each other’s IP
   addresses , communication can be established - we have a full mesh!